# Range belonging checker (Python)

Tags: python

I have multiple ranges and want to find out which range should the number fit between. The ranges are continous within a finited range. Is there any faster way to implement the below algorithm?

```
def range_checker(x: float) -> str:
    for i in range(len(range_list) - 1):
        if range_list[i] <= x < range_list[i + 1]:
            return f"{x} in the range {range_list[i]}, {range_list[i + 1]}"
    return "x is out of range"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    range_list = [-0.2, -0.1, -0.5, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.5]
    print(range_checker(-0.23))
    # -0.23 in the range -0.5, 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work on the provided example which is great.
Also, it uses the `__name__ == "__main__"` guard and type annotations which are a nice touch.
Let's see how things can be improved further.

**Globals**

Your code relies on the global `range_list` to be set. The function would be easier to use, to test, to document, to maintain if this list was provided as a parameter.

**Documentation**

As briefly mentionned previously, the `range_checker` function probably deserves a bit of documentation, for instance as a docstring.

**Loops**

In Python, there is often a better solution that using `range` and `len` to iterate over an array. For more explanations about this, I highly recommend [Ned Batchelder's talk "Loop like a native"](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html).

In your case, it may be easier to first move the "pairing" logic in a function on its own:

```
def pairwise(a):
    for i in range(len(a)-1):
        yield a[i], a[i+1]

def range_checker(x: float, range_list) -> str:
    for a, b in pairwise(range_list):
        if a <= x < b:
            return f"{x} in the range {a}, {b}"
    return "x is out of range"
```

This is also a bit of an excuse to learn about the following concepts:

- tuple unpacking
- iterators
- yield

Then, you can replace the `pairwise` implementation with [any implementation you can find online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764782/iterate-through-pairs-of-items-in-a-python-list).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have a little question about the efficiency of the code, seems to be using yield, and two for loops is O(n^2)?

Comment: Things are slighly more tricky than this because we do not have nested loops per se. Somehow, it is the same as having `for a, b in zip(range_list, range_list[1:])` which is a single loop (O(n)). The only difference is that the logic is moved elsewhere to be able to change the implementation easily if need be.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have tested the speed of the code, it seems that the code I provided is faster than your answer in this case, is it the real case? If yes, do you think I should still write it in your way for the good practise of using yield? Also, may I ask where is the good place(book, online tutorial, google etc) I can study these knowledge, for example: how the yield works under the hood which perform (O(n)) etc. Thank you.

Comment: @tung It is quite literally just the same as your code but abstracted out for clarity at the cost of extra overhead for using `yield` and `tuple`s. If you really want a performant `pairwise` implementation for `Collection`, then you should use `def paireise(collection): iterator = iter(collection); next(iterator, None); return zip(collection, iterator)`, which would 1) remove the overhead of using `yield` by letting `zip` run in C, 2) remove the overhead of indexing by relying entirely on iteration, and 3) remove the overhead of constructing a new `tuple` every time due to `zip` optimizations.

Comment: If you want to lookup how `yield` works, you can Google it alongside "generators", which is the special type of function which uses `yield`.

Comment: Thank you so much, abstracted out for clarity at the cost of extra overhead for using `yield` and `tuple`s, it's different than my original thoughts on `yield` must be faster and using less space(it is true in this case I think), it also add the clarity of the code. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Answer (score 1):

To optimize searches of the form where we want to find the first index `i` where `x < items[i]` and `items` is sorted, the `bisect.bisect` function has us covered:

```py
def grade_to_letter(grade):
    if grade < 60:
        return "F"
    elif grade < 70:
        return "D"
    elif grade < 80:
        return "C"
    elif grade < 90:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "A"


from bisect import bisect

GRADES = (60, 70, 80, 90)
LETTERS = ("F", "D", "C", "B", "A")

def grade_to_letter(grade):
    return LETTERS[bisect(GRADES, grade)]
```

Note that the first and last cases (`i == 0` or `i == len(...)`) correspond to your `out of range` case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of repeated index lookups, you could use `zip`:

```py
def range_checker(x: float) -> str:
    # offset the end ranges by 1 using a slice
    for a, b in zip(range_list, range_list[1:]):
        if a <= x < b:
            return f"{x} in the range {a}, {b}"
    return "x is out of range"
```